# How to use Property Editor or Formatter for list in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```java
public class UserDto {
    private List<PreferenceDto> preferences;
}

public class PreferenceDto {
    private String attributeCode;
    private Object attributeValue;
    private String productCode;
    private Float productVersion;
}
```

**option-1**

```java
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
     
        StringTrimmerAndUpperCasePropertyEditor stringTrimmerAndUpperCasePropertyEditor = new StringTrimmerAndUpperCasePropertyEditor();
        binder.registerCustomEditor(List.class, stringTrimmerAndUpperCasePropertyEditor);
       
    }
```

**option-2**

```java
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
     
        StringTrimmerAndUpperCasePropertyEditor stringTrimmerAndUpperCasePropertyEditor = new StringTrimmerAndUpperCasePropertyEditor();
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Object.class, stringTrimmerAndUpperCasePropertyEditor);
       
    }
```

**option-3**

```java
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
     
        StringTrimmerAndUpperCasePropertyEditor stringTrimmerAndUpperCasePropertyEditor = new StringTrimmerAndUpperCasePropertyEditor();
        binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, stringTrimmerAndUpperCasePropertyEditor);
       
    }
```

**option-4**

```java
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
     
        StringTrimmerAndUpperCasePropertyEditor stringTrimmerAndUpperCasePropertyEditor = new StringTrimmerAndUpperCasePropertyEditor();
        binder.registerCustomEditor(PreferenceDto.class, stringTrimmerAndUpperCasePropertyEditor);
       
    }
```

None of the above is calling the editor.

Here is the editor:

```
public class StringTrimmerAndUpperCasePropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    @Override
    public void setAsText(@Nullable String text) {
        System.out.println("setAsText: "+ text);
        setValue(text.trim().toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Here is the controller

```
@PostMapping
    public void createUserAttributes(@Valid @RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
       
        System.out.println(userDto);
    }
```

My requirement is, I need to format the strings before passing to the list of `PreferenceDto`. I have tried many options and checked all the different blogs, but none has answered my query. Can someone please help me with solution or atleast refer me the blog or documentation which includes property editors with list.

Comment: Please add your controller code... Do you use `@ModelAttribute` or `@RequestBody`.

Comment: I use @RequestBody

Comment: Then trying to configure databinding is the wrong option as that isn't used. That is only used when binding form-data/request parameters to an object. Your is using serialization with Jackson (the default) and you should configure that with a Jackson Serializer on the fields you want to process.

Comment: So property editors, formatters, converters work only with @ModelAttribute but not with RequestBody ? Do i need to use to configure custom jackson serializer for RequestBody. Can you please help me with some reference

Comment: You can use `@JsonSerializer` and specify a specific one for the field you want to convert to Upper case. A search on the internet will probably provide a ready to go implementation.

Comment: I think we need deserializer but not serializer, correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Deserializer indeed (even after 30 years as a developer I keep mixing them up :) ).